# Condition on a tower of number field for maximal order to be free.

Tags: number-theory

Take $\mathbb{K}\subset\mathbb{L}$ two number fields.
Then the ring of intgers $\mathfrak{o}_\mathbb{L}$ is 
a projective module over $\mathfrak{o}_\mathbb{K}$.
At which condition this module is free ? Is it related 
to class field theory for $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: The references in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf show $O_L = \mathfrak{a} b_1 \oplus O_K b_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus O_K b_n$ for some $b_n \in O_L$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ a fractional ideal of $O_K$ whose class is independent of the $b_j$

Comment: I agree, but precisely at which condition do we know that $\mathfrak{a}$ is equal to $O_\mathbb{K}$?